# javascript array from json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have below JSON value in variable named "response"

`{"rsuccess":true,"errorMessage":" ","ec":null,"responseList":[{"id":2,"description":"user1"},{"id":1,"description”:"user2"}]}`

```
var users=response.responseList; 
var l = users.length;
```

but it gives me error

`[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'users.length')`

Comment: What does it tell you when you run this code: `console.log(typeof response)`?

Comment: Are you sure the variable contains that value? Do you print it immediately before the line where you try to take the users' length? Commonly, this kind of thing smells of an asynchronicity error, where you are reading a variable before the variable receives its value. Not sure whether it is or is not until we actually see the code...

Comment: Check out my answer, it should answer your question @raheem52.

Comment: First check can you get array in users ?  ` console,log(users) `

Comment: @dfsq  console.log(typeof response) gives me object

Answer (score 1):

After getting `response` from callback, you need to parse the JSON string to object...using

```
JSON.parse(response);
```

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar var advs1=JSON.parse(response); 
gives

JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"

Comment: @raheem52 That means `response` is of type `object`!..In that case.. `response.responseList.length` must be returning `2` unless `response` does not have `responseList`.. If possible, could you share link to which you are making some ajax request returning the JSON object ?

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted? I stated the same thing as you, before you did, but in a clearer manner.

Answer (score 0):

in case you haven't noticed ,you have a syntax error in this line

```
[{"id":2,"description":"user1"},{"id":1,"description”:"user2"}]}
```

the double quote isn't properly closed around description identifier.Change it to:

```
{"id":1,"description":"user2"}
```

Then it will work just fine

Answer (score -1):

**Undefined variables are not objects, and therefore can not have properties such as length.**

---

You have not converted your JSON into an object.

Do so as follows:

`var obj = eval("(" + json + ')');`

`eval()` executes the code and creates a native JavaScript object.

However, a lot of people criticize `eval()` if it is handling unsanitized input.

The best bet is to use this native JavaScript function: `JSON.parse(jsonString);`, which was made specifically for this purpose- to parse JSON and to make it an object.

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse